# Update column with String prefix

Tags: sql, sql-update, oracle-sqldeveloper

Im triying to `UPDATE` a column named `INV_SUPPLIER`, I must add `ES` prefix to `INV_SUPPLIER` if the column does not start with `ES` AND does not contain `NO_VALIDO` AND `IS NOT NULL`

Column declaration:
                                        Nullable  Default
    INV_SUPPLIER    VARCHAR2(32 BYTE)   Yes

When I select:

```
SELECT * 
    FROM 
        EFAC_INVOICE f 
    WHERE 
        f.INV_SUPPLIER NOT LIKE 'ES%' 
    AND 
        f.INV_SUPPLIER NOT LIKE 'NO_VALIDO'
    AND 
        f.INV_SUPPLIER IS NOT NULL;
```

Seems to give me the correct data.

But when I tri to update:

```
UPDATE EFAC_INVOICE f 
    SET 
        f.INV_SUPPLIER='ES'+f.INV_SUPPLIER 
    WHERE 
        f.INV_SUPPLIER NOT LIKE 'ES%' 
    AND 
        f.INV_SUPPLIER NOT LIKE 'NO_VALIDO'
    AND 
        f.INV_SUPPLIER IS NOT NULL;
```

But throws me the error:

> Error SQL: ORA-01722: número no válido
>   01722. 00000 -  "invalid number"
>   *Cause:    The specified number was invalid.
>   *Action:   Specify a valid number.

Any idea where I'm wrong???

Comment: what RDBMS?  use `||` to concat in oracle. use `+` in SQL server.  you also have an ; before your last check.

Comment: love u @xQbert ! I only found + to concat in SQL...  post it as answer!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `||` to concat in oracle. use `+` in SQL server. you also have an extra `;` before your last check

Comment: 11 minutes remaining to accept... ;) thanks!! i will leave office on time todayyy